# How to fit a mixed model with a skew normal distribution in python?

Tags: mixed-model, python, group-differences, skew-normal-distribution

I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this so if not, please let me know,

however I am using `StatsModels` to create a mixed effects model that assesses the relationship between a factored predictor and continuous dependent variable, taking into account group effects.

```
model = smf.mixedlm("continuous_dv ~ factored_predictor", df, groups=df['group'])
```

The challenge is that the underlying data has a skewed normal distribution, and I am not sure how to fit a mixed model with that distribution in Python?

In R there is a package `skewlmm` which allows for this, and I am wondering what the counterpart would be in Python (if it exists?).

I have seen the following links

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140371/scipy-skewnormal-fitting

and similar which show how to fit data INTO a skew normal distribution by using `skewnormfit()`

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ordinarily the *marginal* distributions of the data are not subject to any assumptions in a regression model.  What do the *conditional* responses look like?

Comment: They show a slightly bimodal skew-normal distribution.

Comment: You very well could be fine with a standard model, depending on how much data you have and how strong the skewness and bimodality are.  There's no way you're going to accommodate the bimodality through any reasonably simple distributional assumption, suggesting you might be better off changing your thinking to assessing how useful and accurate it might be to use a plain vanilla mixed model rather than seeking an alternative.

Comment: R package brms can fit Bayesian mixed effects models with a skew normal distribution. I've never tried it but a Python interface has been developed: https://github.com/adamhaber/pybrms

Comment: Thank you for sending that link! Unfortunately I am unable to get even their test code to work so not 100% sure what the issue is (looks like this is a problem others have encountered as well based on my preliminary research)